# Delphi compiling to Linux ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplrtl270.so

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney, paserver

After upgrading to Delphi 10.4.1 , I installed PAServer on Linux Ubunto 18.04.5 and updated SDK Local File Cache , there were no errors in these processes.

However when I converted my existing applications or tried to create a new one for Linux-64 I got the following error :

```
> [DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find
> bplrtl270.so
```

following this error there may others :

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplemsserverapi270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bpldbrtl270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplbindengine270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplbindcomp270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplRESTComponents270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplFireDAC270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplFireDACCommon270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplFireDACCommonDriver270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplxmlrtl270.so
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find bplFireDACOracleDriver270.so
```

I've already checked a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023217/delphi-linux-ld-linux-exe-error-cannot-find-lgcc-s) , followed their suggestions , but I have no success , maybe due to different Delphi version!

Thks in advance for you help !

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem today. First thing is to check do you have these files. If no - you can try to reinstall Linux64 platform (recommendation found on other forum).

If you have these files but Delphi can't find them (my case) - you can try to add path to the library. I found my "so" files in "...Studio\21.0\binlinux64". So way to add is:

Options- Language - Delphi - Library - select "Linux Platform" - Library path - add "$(BDS)\binlinux64"

Comment: thanks for the tips.  I tried to reinstall Linux64 platform a couple of times, with no success. Then I did the following : copied contents from "...Studio\21.0\binlinux64"  to "..\Studio\21.0\Redist\linux64"  then it all worked fine!   Thanks.