# delphi alexandria linux error ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: linux, ubuntu, delphi

I install wsl on windows 10 and install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and open linux terminal and run this commands :
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install joe wget p7zip-full curl openssh-server build-essential zlib1g-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libncurses5
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

then i Unpack the LinuxPAServer22.0.tar.gz and run it and Creating a Connection Profile in delphi and Adding the Installed SDK to Delphi.

i create consol application in Delphi
Delphi in "Linking" show 138 error :

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lgcc_s
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lc
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -ldl
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lpthread
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lm
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::__malloc(NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::__free(void*): error: undefined reference to 'free'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::pthread_once(int&, void (*)()): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_once'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::pthread_key_create(unsigned int&, void (*)(void*)): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_create'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::dladdr(NativeUInt, dl_info&): error: undefined reference to 'dladdr'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::dlopen(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::dlclose(NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'dlclose'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::dlsym(NativeUInt, char*): error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::TlsGetValue(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\SysInit.o:SysInit:function Sysinit::TlsSetValue(unsigned int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setspecific'
  SysInit.pas:1183: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
  System.pas:18011: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
  System.pas:684: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
  System.pas:17929: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
  System.pas:688: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
  System.pas:18519: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::getenv(char*): error: undefined reference to 'getenv'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__malloc(NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::calloc(NativeUInt, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'calloc'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::realloc(void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'realloc'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__free(void*): error: undefined reference to 'free'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__exit(int): error: undefined reference to 'exit'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::memmove(void*, void const*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'memmove'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::memset(void*, int, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'memset'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::strlen(char*): error: undefined reference to 'strlen'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__raise(int): error: undefined reference to 'raise'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::pthread_self(): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_self'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::sched_yield(): error: undefined reference to 'sched_yield'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::dladdr(NativeUInt, dl_info&): error: undefined reference to 'dladdr'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::dlopen(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::dlclose(NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'dlclose'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::dlsym(NativeUInt, char*): error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::dlerror(): error: undefined reference to 'dlerror'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::open(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'open'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__chdir(char*): error: undefined reference to 'chdir'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__close(int): error: undefined reference to 'close'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fchdir(int): error: undefined reference to 'fchdir'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::ftruncate(int, long): error: undefined reference to 'ftruncate'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::getcwd(char*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'getcwd'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::lseek(int, long, int): error: undefined reference to 'lseek'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__read(int, void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'read'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::readlink(char*, char*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'readlink'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::sysconf(int): error: undefined reference to 'sysconf'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::usleep(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'usleep'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__write(int, void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'write'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::iconv(void*, char**, NativeUInt*, char**, NativeUInt*): error: undefined reference to 'iconv'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::iconv_open(char*, char*): error: undefined reference to 'iconv_open'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::iconv_close(void*): error: undefined reference to 'iconv_close'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::stat(char*, _stat&): error: undefined reference to 'stat'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::mmap(void*, NativeUInt, int, int, int, long): error: undefined reference to 'mmap'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::munmap(void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'munmap'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::__error(): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::wcscoll_l(int const*, int const*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'wcscoll_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::towupper_l(unsigned int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'towupper_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::setlocale(int, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'setlocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::newlocale(int, char const*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'newlocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::times(tms&): error: undefined reference to 'times'
  ex.inc:84: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
  ex.inc:171: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fegetexceptflag(unsigned short*, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'fegetexceptflag'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fesetexceptflag(unsigned short*, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'fesetexceptflag'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fegetround(): error: undefined reference to 'fegetround'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fesetround(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'fesetround'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::fedisableexcept(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'fedisableexcept'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::libm_cosl(long double): error: undefined reference to 'cosl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::libm_sinl(long double): error: undefined reference to 'sinl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::libm_atanl(long double): error: undefined reference to 'atanl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::libm_sqrtl(long double): error: undefined reference to 'sqrtl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::llrintl(long double): error: undefined reference to 'llrintl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_RaiseException(_Unwind_Exception&): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_RaiseException'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_GetRegionStart(_Unwind_Context*): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetRegionStart'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData(_Unwind_Context*): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_GetGR(_Unwind_Context*, int): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetGR'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_SetGR(_Unwind_Context*, int, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_SetGR'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_GetIP(_Unwind_Context*): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetIP'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_SetIP(_Unwind_Context*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_SetIP'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dlfcn.o:Posix.Dlfcn:function Posix::Dlfcn::dladdr(NativeUInt, dl_info&): error: undefined reference to 'dladdr'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dlfcn.o:Posix.Dlfcn:function Posix::Dlfcn::dlopen(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dlfcn.o:Posix.Dlfcn:function Posix::Dlfcn::dlclose(NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'dlclose'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dlfcn.o:Posix.Dlfcn:function Posix::Dlfcn::dlsym(NativeUInt, char*): error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Fcntl.o:Posix.Fcntl:function Posix::Fcntl::__open(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'open'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Fcntl.o:Posix.Fcntl:function Posix::Fcntl::fcntl(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'fcntl'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.SysStat.o:Posix.SysStat:function Posix::Sysstat::fstat(int, _stat&): error: undefined reference to 'fstat'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.SysStat.o:Posix.SysStat:function Posix::Sysstat::lstat(char*, _stat&): error: undefined reference to 'lstat'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.SysStat.o:Posix.SysStat:function Posix::Sysstat::stat(char*, _stat&): error: undefined reference to 'stat'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Signal.o:Posix.Signal:function Posix::Signal::sigaction(int, sigaction_t*, sigaction_t*): error: undefined reference to 'sigaction'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Signal.o:Posix.Signal:function Posix::Signal::sigaddset(sigset_t&, int): error: undefined reference to 'sigaddset'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Signal.o:Posix.Signal:function Posix::Signal::kill(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'kill'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Time.o:Posix.Time:function Posix::Time::clock_gettime(int, timespec*): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Time.o:Posix.Time:function Posix::Time::localtime_r(long&, tm&): error: undefined reference to 'localtime_r'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.SysTime.o:Posix.SysTime:function Posix::Systime::gettimeofday(timeval&, void*): error: undefined reference to 'gettimeofday'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Locale.o:Posix.Locale:function Posix::Locale::localeconv(): error: undefined reference to 'localeconv'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Locale.o:Posix.Locale:function Posix::Locale::newlocale(int, char const*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'newlocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Locale.o:Posix.Locale:function Posix::Locale::freelocale(void*): error: undefined reference to 'freelocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Locale.o:Posix.Locale:function Posix::Locale::duplocale(void*): error: undefined reference to 'duplocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Locale.o:Posix.Locale:function Posix::Locale::uselocale(void*): error: undefined reference to 'uselocale'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Iconv.o:Posix.Iconv:function Posix::Iconv::iconv_open(char*, char*): error: undefined reference to 'iconv_open'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Iconv.o:Posix.Iconv:function Posix::Iconv::iconv_close(void*): error: undefined reference to 'iconv_close'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dirent.o:Posix.Dirent:function Posix::Dirent::closedir(__dirstream*): error: undefined reference to 'closedir'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dirent.o:Posix.Dirent:function Posix::Dirent::opendir(char*): error: undefined reference to 'opendir'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Dirent.o:Posix.Dirent:function Posix::Dirent::readdir_r(__dirstream*, dirent*, dirent*&): error: undefined reference to 'readdir_r'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Errno.o:Posix.Errno:function Posix::Errno::__error(): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Fnmatch.o:Posix.Fnmatch:function Posix::Fnmatch::fnmatch(char*, char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'fnmatch'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Langinfo.o:Posix.Langinfo:function Posix::Langinfo::nl_langinfo(int): error: undefined reference to 'nl_langinfo'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Langinfo.o:Posix.Langinfo:function Posix::Langinfo::nl_langinfo_l(int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'nl_langinfo_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Pthread.o:Posix.Pthread:function Posix::Pthread::pthread_self(): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_self'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.String_.o:Posix.String_:function Posix::String_::memcmp(void const*, void const*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'memcmp'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.String_.o:Posix.String_:function Posix::String_::strcmp(char*, char*): error: undefined reference to 'strcmp'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.String_.o:Posix.String_:function Posix::String_::strerror_r_GNU(int, char*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'strerror_r'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Unistd.o:Posix.Unistd:function Posix::Unistd::euidaccess(char*, int): error: undefined reference to 'access'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Unistd.o:Posix.Unistd:function Posix::Unistd::__close(int): error: undefined reference to 'close'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Unistd.o:Posix.Unistd:function Posix::Unistd::getpid(): error: undefined reference to 'getpid'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Unistd.o:Posix.Unistd:function Posix::Unistd::__read(int, void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'read'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Unistd.o:Posix.Unistd:function Posix::Unistd::__write(int, void*, NativeUInt): error: undefined reference to 'write'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_destroy(sem_t&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_destroy'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_getvalue(sem_t&, int&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_getvalue'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_init(sem_t&, int, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'sem_init'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_post(sem_t&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_post'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_trywait(sem_t&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_trywait'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_wait(sem_t&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_wait'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Semaphore.o:Posix.Semaphore:function Posix::Semaphore::sem_timedwait(sem_t&, timespec&): error: undefined reference to 'sem_timedwait'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.SysUtsname.o:Posix.SysUtsname:function Posix::Sysutsname::uname(utsname&): error: undefined reference to 'uname'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Wchar.o:Posix.Wchar:function Posix::Wchar::wcscoll_l(int const*, int const*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'wcscoll_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Wchar.o:Posix.Wchar:function Posix::Wchar::wcscasecmp_l(int const*, int const*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'wcscasecmp_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Wctype.o:Posix.Wctype:function Posix::Wctype::towupper(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'towupper'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Wctype.o:Posix.Wctype:function Posix::Wctype::towlower_l(unsigned int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'towlower_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\Posix.Wctype.o:Posix.Wctype:function Posix::Wctype::towupper_l(unsigned int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'towupper_l'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.Internal.ExcUtils.o:System.Internal.ExcUtils:function System::Internal::Excutils::TlsGetValue(int): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific'
  System.SysUtils.pas:988: error: undefined reference to 'memset'
  System.SysUtils.pas:988: error: undefined reference to 'memset'
  System.SysUtils.pas:29787: error: undefined reference to 'memset'
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Linux64\debug\System.SysUtils.o:System.SysUtils:function System::Sysutils::gnu_get_libc_version(): error: undefined reference to 'gnu_get_libc_version'
```

Comment: Try some of the answers to a question for the same error with normal Linux VM : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023217/delphi-linux-ld-linux-exe-error-cannot-find-lgcc-s

Comment: Thanks @Brian
I have examined similar problems before. It did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a non-English name in the defined path of the BDSPLATFORMSDKSDIR variable. I created a new folder and changed the path to that folder. The new folder used only English letters. This solved my problem.
Due to the use of onedrive Windows, the name mydocument was changed to a non-English name